# Docker solidity file outside of allowed directories

Tags: docker, solidity, solc

I am compiling my smart contracts using Docker and have the following command.

```
docker run -v /home/user/go-ethereum-v1/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.4 '--allow-paths=/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/' -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Pigfox.sol
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Source "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
```

The confirmed import path is:

```
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
```

In the contract I have

import `"/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";`

I have tried putting the ERC20.sol file in the same directory but it has mulptiple dependencies so it become spaghetti code.

Any idea how I can fix the allow --allow-paths to the install directory?

Comment: `/home/user/.nvm/...` isn't going to exist in the container. You are mapping your code to `/sources` inside the container. Any imports will need to be relative to work in both places. And you should install `@openzeppelin` as a dependency in your project, not globally.